# SQL delete row with one to one relation

Tags: typescript, sqlite, typeorm

I have those two entities:

```
export class MyEntity {
    ...

    @OneToOne(() => Item, (item) => item.entity)
    item: Item:

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.createdMyEntities)
    createdBy: User;

    ...
}

export class Item {
    ...

    @OneToOne(() => MyEntity, (myEntity) => myEntity.item)
    @JoinColumn()
    entity: MyEntity;

    ...
}
```

I want to delete a row in `MyEntity` but that will give a an `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` error. I don't want to also delete the `Item`, I just want to delete the `MyEntity` and remove the relation to it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting one-to-one relation can be tricky as sometime it give `Foreign Key` error and you can play with multiple cascade options to see if anything works here. Another workaround which can work is selecting() the rows you want to delete and joining based on foreign key, then for the rows that comes you can simply update those foreign key column to remove the relation and finally you can delete your desired rows. I am attaching sample code for your reference:

```js
// Assuming you have a repository or a database connection instance
const myEntityRepository = /* Initialize your repository or connection */ ;

// Find the MyEntity instance you want to delete
const myEntityToDelete = await myEntityRepository.findOne( /* your conditions here */ );

if (myEntityToDelete) {
  // Remove the association between MyEntity and Item
  myEntityToDelete.item = null;

  // Save the changes to update the entity without the association
  await myEntityRepository.save(myEntityToDelete);

  // Now you can safely delete the MyEntity instance
  await myEntityRepository.remove(myEntityToDelete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the @OneTOOne definition of relation, set cascade to persist, and merge only.